Huggingface requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url
I am trying to push a dataset to hub, the repo-name and token is set correctly, but I am getting this error:

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/api/models/aben118/common_voice_16_2_hi_pseudo_labelled/revision/main


Repository Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/api/models/aben118/common_voice_16_2_hi_pseudo_labelled/revision/main.
Please make sure you specified the correct repo_id and repo_type.
If you are trying to access a private or gated repo, make sure you are authenticated.


To duplicate:
from huggingface_hub import HfFolder, create_repo, get_full_repo_name, snapshot_download, upload_folder
create_repo("aben118/common_voice_16_1_hi_pseudo_labelled", repo_type="dataset", exist_ok=True, token=<your_token>)
snapshot_download(repo_id="aben118/common_voice_16_1_hi_pseudo_labelled", local_dir="./common_voice_16_1_hi_pseudo_labelled")


resolved after adding repo_type="dataset" in
snapshot_download(repo_id="aben118/common_voice_16_1_hi_pseudo_labelled", repo_type="dataset", local_dir="./common_voice_16_1_hi_pseudo_labelled")

